# Is it possible to access the hexdump of a packet in PyShark?

Tags: python, tshark, hexdump, pyshark

I am using `pyshark` to open and parse `pcap` files. Currently I've been able to access the packet fields. But I cannot seem to find a way to access the `hexdump` value of each packet. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54140103/765294).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the homepage of PyShark:

> [PyShark] doesn't actually parse any packets, it simply uses tshark's (wireshark command-line utility) ability to export XMLs to use its parsing.

The XML exported by tshark is either [PSML (Packet Summary Markup Language)](http://www.nbee.org/doku.php?id=netpdl:psml_specification) or [PDML (Packet Details Markup Language)](http://www.nbee.org/doku.php?id=netpdl:pdml_specification) and neither of these format store the full hexadecimal dump of packets.

After digging into the source code and considering the point above, I can say that the feature you are looking for is not implemented in PyShark.

Comment: This answer is wrong as far as I can tell. In all my tests the PDML output that Pyshark uses contains the full payload hexdump as the value of the field named "data.data", which is accessible as-is in Pyshark -- see my answer to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54140103/765294).